# iOS: How to Enable UIScrollView Panning on Long Press

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uiscrollview

I can enable/disable scrolling effectively by using the `scrollView.scrollEnabled` property.

Currently I enable scrolling when the state of the `longPressRecognizer` is `UIGestureStateBegan` and disable scrolling when it's `UIGestureStateEnded`.

When I longPress and then drag my finger, the scrollView doesn't scroll.

I think that somehow the scrollView's `panGestureRecognizer` isn't getting the touch events, which is weird since the `scrollView` is **(I checked using the touchesBegan, touchesMoved, etc. methods)**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `UIScrollView` is not getting touches, because touch started before you enabled scrolling on UIScrollView. This sample code manages scrolling for you with the `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`, scrolling a big UIImageView:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
@IBOutlet var gr: UILongPressGestureRecognizer!
var initialPos = CGPointZero
var dragPos = CGPointZero

// This action is bound to long press gesture recognizer within Interface Builder
@IBAction func longpressHandler(sender: UILongPressGestureRecognizer) {
    if sender.state == .Began {
        // Save initial position for moving
        initialPos = sender.locationInView(scrollView)
    }
    else if sender.state == .Changed {
        // Get new drag location
        let loc = sender.locationInView(scrollView)
        let newPos = CGPoint(x: initialPos.x - loc.x + dragPos.x, y: initialPos.y - loc.y + dragPos.y)
        dragPos = newPos
        scrollView.contentOffset = newPos
    }
    else if sender.state == .Ended {
        // Check for end position of the content, snap it back to the edge of the screen if moved too far
        var newOffset = scrollView.contentOffset
        var move = false
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x < 0 {
            newOffset.x = 0
            move = true
        }
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y < 0 {
            newOffset.y = 0
            move = true
        }
        if scrollView.contentOffset.x > photo.frame.size.width - scrollView.frame.size.width {
            newOffset.x = max(self.photo.frame.size.width - self.scrollView.frame.size.width, 0)
            move = true
        }
        if scrollView.contentOffset.y > photo.frame.size.height - scrollView.frame.size.height {
            newOffset.y = max(self.photo.frame.size.height - self.scrollView.frame.size.height, 0)
            move = true
        }
        if move {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.25, animations: {
                self.scrollView.contentOffset = newOffset
            })
        }
    }
}

var photo = UIImageView(image: UIImage(named: "photo"))

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Set up your scrollview
    scrollView.addSubview(photo)
    scrollView.contentSize = photo.frame.size

    // add the long press gesture recognizer to the scrollview
    scrollView.addGestureRecognizer(gr)
}
```